# Spark output to kafka exactly-once

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I want to output spark and spark streaming to kafka exactly-once  . But as the doc says 
*"Output operations (like foreachRDD) have at-least once semantics, that is, the transformed data may get written to an external entity more than once in the event of a worker failure. ".*
To do transactional updates, spark recommends to use the batch time (available in foreachRDD) and the partition index of the RDD to create an identifier. This identifier uniquely identifies a blob data in the streaming application. Code listed below:

```
dstream.foreachRDD { (rdd, time) =>
  rdd.foreachPartition { partitionIterator =>
    val partitionId = TaskContext.get.partitionId()
    val **uniqueId** = generateUniqueId(time.milliseconds, partitionId)
    // use this uniqueId to transactionally commit the data in  partitionIterator
  }
}
```

But how to use the **uniqueId** in kafka to make transactionally committing.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

An exactly-once solution with Kafka was discussed at a Spark Summit by Cody Koeninger, a Senior Software Engineer at Kixer. Essentially, this solution involves storing offsets and data with a simultaneous commit.

In mentioning the exactly once topic to engineers at a Confluent meetup in 2016, the engineers referenced Cody's lecture on this topic. Cloudera published his lecture at http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/exactly-once-spark-streaming-from-apache-kafka/. Cody's paper is at http://koeninger.github.io/kafka-exactly-once/#1 and his github (for this topic) is at https://github.com/koeninger/kafka-exactly-once. There are also videos of his lecture that can be found on the web.

Later versions of Kafka introduce Kafka Streams to take care of the exactly-once scenario without Spark, but that topic is only worth a footnote as the frame of the question is to work with Spark.